# Positioning image insert in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I was writing a Google Chrome extension to insert an image into the body of a website. It currently does that, but the image is centered all the way at the bottom, after the text of the website. I was wondering how to put it in the top left instead, or to use coordinates for the location. This is my code currently in JavaScript, as I can't use CSS for it.

````
  function imageappend() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("imageedit_1_3932659157.png");
    img.style.top = "0";
    img.style.left = "0";
    img.style.padding = "0";
    img.style.margin = "0";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }

  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: imageappend
  });
})(); ```
````

Comment: Add `img.style.position = 'absolute'` or `'fixed'`

Comment: For the second time today, thank you so much! You're a lifesaver :)

Comment: I had one last question (figured I would enter it in the same area) - how would I change the width? It's still at the same width as it was before, even though I set it to be 10% instead.